# Consuming more memory instead of require?

Tags: ram

I had install ubuntu 64 bit on my system (ubuntu 12.04 lts).

When I do `free -m`

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          5859       5284        574          0        251       4012
-/+ buffers/cache:       1021       4838
Swap:         6032          0       6032
```

I have total 6GB of RAM, now even I had just one application in used it show me 5284 are totally used, only 574 MB of memory is free.

What to do to resolved it or to debug it ?

Also when I fire TOP command, it show only few application running as in my system, but occupied memory are very much?

Comment: http://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Comment: No, it is showing you that 1 GB is used.  Pay attention to the -/+ buffers/cache line.

Answer (score 0):

Use system monitor to see which process is devouring all your memory to get a possible idea of what you should do next.

[image: snap1]

You can do the same with `top`; use <kbd>**Shift**</kbd> + <kbd>**<**</kbd> / <kbd>**>**</kbd> key combos to select the memory usage column, and <kbd>**Shift**</kbd> + <kbd>**R**</kbd> to toggle the reverse-state of column sort.

[image: snap2]

You can then kill the process that's causing the problem.